# Сортировка Dictionary по values

Tags: c#, словари

Имеется словарь

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Man> Mans.
```

Класс Man:

```
protected class Man
{
 protected string name;
 protected int age;
}
```

Вся работа со словарем в части получения данных ведется через int ключ словаря(TryGetValue). Необходимо при добавлении нового элемента в словарь сортировать его по полю age объекта Man. 
Я знаю про SortedDictionary, однако там сортировка происходит по ключу, а мне необходимо сделать тоже самое, только по полю объекта Man. Важно сортировать именно при добавлении, а не постфактум, так как количество данных очень велико. Есть ли какая-то возможность сделать это?

Comment: В такой структуре данных может быть только один человек с каждым значением age. Так задумано? :)

Comment: Кого сортировать? Словарь? о_О

Comment: нет, пример абстрактный) исходя из него age у всех уникальный)) Но в реальности это естественно не возраст)

Comment: сортировать именно словарь. Как я уже писал, нет проблем отсортировать VALUES в нужный момент и отдать потребителю, однако это очень тяжело. Проще это делать сразу.

Comment: Тогда почему бы не держать отдельно `SortedSet<Value>`, и добавлять в него когда надо? // Ага, это уже предложено в ответе.

Comment: Это решение мне не кажется best practices. Расходы по памяти критичны. Если есть более изящные идеи - был бы рад их услышать. В любом случае - огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Sleeeper: А вы в любом случае проигрываете либо по времени (пересортировка перед выдачей), либо по памяти (держать заранее подготовленный список). Choose your poison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя обеспечить одновременно эффективный поиск по age + сортировку по name в рамках одной структуры данных. В базах данных эту проблему решают введением индексов - по сути, еще одного Dictionary, который хранит данные уже по name. Так что вам проще всего будет пойти по тому же пути:

1. Объявить дополнительную коллекцию, которая будет хранить те же элементы, но уже с сортировкой по name. Например, [`ImmutableSortedSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467193(v=vs.111).aspx) с comparer-ом по имени.
2. При добавлении элемента - добавлять его и в основной Dictionary, и в коллекцию для сортировки по имени.
3. Если нужно - обернуть все это в свой класс-коллекцию, которая будет реализовать поиск через основной словарь, а в качестве Enumerator-а для перебора - возвращать Enumerator из отсортированной коллекции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! На самом деле это было первым, что пришло в голову - дублировать словарь. Однако тут возникает вопрос памяти. В любом случае - огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Sleeeper объекты же будут лежать в памяти всего один раз - т.е. память вы потратите только на саму структуру данных, позволяющую быстро выбрать отсортированные объекты. Стоит взять и померять расходы в реальном приложении.